# Symfony service attem

Tags: symfony

i'm trying to configure services in symfony2:

**services.yml**

```
parameters:
    trendio.user_provider.class: Trendio\DelivBundle\TrendioUserProvider
    trendio.rest.class: Trendio\DelivBundle\Services\TrendioRest
    trendio.rest.backend_ip: 192.168.0.102
services:
    trendio_rest:
        class: %trendio.rest.class%
        arguments: [%trendio.rest.backend_ip%,@serializer,@buzz]
```

I got a error :

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "TrendioRest" from namespace "Trendio\DelivBundle\Services" in /var/www/deliv/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3176. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

**TrendioRest.php**

```
<?php

namespace Trendio\DelivBundle\Services;

class TrendioRest { ... }
```

But,if i move class to top-level bundle namespace (Trendio\DelivBundle), service worked correctly. Why class doesn't load load from sub-folders namespaces?

Comment: Can you please specify the path to the file that contains `TrendioRest ` class? Is it placed according to PSR-0? If using Symfony2 without any customizations, the path should be `<project root>/src/Trendio/DelivBundle/Services/TrendioRest.php`

Comment: Yes, path is {root}/src/Trendio/DelivBundle/Services/TrendioRest.php

Answer (score 0):

It's best practise to use Symfony class

**Since [new Symfony 3.3 DI features](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/) you can simplify it** like this:

```
parameters:
    trendio.rest.backend_ip: 192.168.0.102

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true 

    Trendio\DelivBundle\TrendioUserProvider: ~
    Trendio\DelivBundle\Services\TrendioRest:
        arguments: [%trendio.rest.backend_ip%]
```